# detecting browser scrolling

Tags: javascript

How can I know when the user has scroll on the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could subscribe for the [window.onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll) event. Example:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    // the user scrolled the window
};
```